# Convert parse value into proper format in python

Tags: python, vectorization, pca, tf-idf

I have dataframe which contains this kind of data...

```
     user_name  audit_status    IP
  0   deck_man    Success     192.168.1.19  
  1    devid      Failed      192.168.1.14
```

After converting it to vector using `tf-idf` I have the following result:

```
      user_name                                               audit_status                                   IP
 0  (0, 4)\t1.0\n (1, 0)\t1.0\n (2, 3)\t1.0\n ...       (0, 1)\t1.0\n (1, 1)\t1.0\n (2, 0)\t1.0\n ..   (0, 5)\t0.431952109640923\n (0, 3)\t0.43195...
```

Now `type` of that value is `45x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>' with 45 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format`

My goal is to convert this data to vector form and then pass it into a PCA to reduce the dimensions (because it contains many more columns as well).

if I pass into the `PCA` this kind of data it gives me the error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

What is the solution for this??

PCA takes this kind of data (here is the Example)

```
       x            y       z
0   -2.264542   0.505704    0.604580
```

How can I do that?

Help will be appreciated.